# How to make sure display of laptop is actually matte?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, laptop-display

I am trying to find acceptable configuration of Lenovo Y50-70 on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=lenovo+y50-70+SSD+i7+16gb+512gb&rh=i%3Aaps%2Ck%3Alenovo+y50-70+SSD+i7+16gb+512gb). How to be 100% sure that display is FullHD, IPS and matte? What words / terms describe that? Any examples?

What about this models:

[One](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013GYY64W)

[Two](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00V7RJH0E)

[Three](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KYI7WTA)

Comment: Lenovo calls their matte displays "AntiGlare": This Wiki is German but it shows the names of matte displays by Brand. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glare-Type-Display#Markenbezeichnungen_matter_Anzeigen

Answer (score 2):

Your **first option** is a Y50 **TOUCH** as you can see in the technical details section at the bottom.
It has a Full-HD (1920x1080 in technical details) AntiGlare display (that should be matte) LED Panel (see product description at the top).

Your **second option** is a 'normal' Y50 (no touch).
It has a Full-HD IPS LED-Backlight display. It does not say anything about matte/AntiGlare though, neither does Lenovo itself on their [website](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/y-series/y50/?sb=:000001C9:000143F9:).

Your **third option** is a Y50 **UHD**.
It has an UHD (3840x2160) Display. It does not say anything about matte/AntiGlare and I could not even find that specific model (59421859 - model number from the technical details section) on their [website](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/lenovo/y-series/y50-uhd/). But all other Y50 UHD variants listed on this website do have 'Glossy' displays.

So as far as I can see, you are searching for that second option.
Hope that helps.